# Concatenate a string and decimal in a Linq query

Tags: c#, linq

I am writing an application in VS2010, Framework 4.0, C# and silverlight 4.

I have a simple class and Linq Query.

The class is:

```
public class pmDues
    {
        [Key]
        public int DuesID { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string dues_type { get; set; }
        public decimal dues_amount { get; set; }
    }
```

In my DomainService I have the following IQueryable:

```
public IQueryable<pmdues> GetDues()
   {
      return from dues in ObjectContext.tblDuesRates
                  orderby dues.due_type
         select new pmDues()
            {
              DuesID = dues.id,
              dues_type = dues.due_type,
              dues_amount = dues.amount.Value
              };
        }
```

So far so good.......But!

What I really want is to display the dues_type + dues_amount concatenated. The dues_amount is declared as a decimal in the SQL Server table. What I don't know is where and how to concatenate dues_type with dues_amount. I tried the following but it did not work. Should I do the concatenation in the class? If so how. Still kind of new to C#.

```
public IQueryable<pmdues> GetDues()
   {
      return from dues in ObjectContext.tblDuesRates
                  orderby dues.due_type
         select new pmDues()
            {
              DuesID = dues.id,
              dues_type = dues.due_type + " - " + 
                          dues.amount.Value.ToString(),
              dues_amount = dues.amount.Value
              };
        }
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you let us know what "I tried the following but it did not work" means? What happened that let you know it didn't work?

Comment: Don't concatenate strings, it's always a bad idea. Use String.Format instead.  I'll bet that `dues.amount` is null so `dues.amount.Value` throws a NullReferenceException. Try `String.Format("{0} - {1}",dues.due_type,dues.amount)`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos `String.Format` doesn't work in entity framework/linq to entities.

Comment: @DavidSherret you're right. In fact, I wonder whether the actual error isn't that `ToString` can't be called. If the OP doesn't post the actual error, we're all just guessing. Eg, if `amount` is null, not only will `ToString` throw but the assignment to `dues_amount` as well.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yeah, the error and technology used here is definitely not clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`SqlFunctions.StringConvert`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd466276(v=vs.110).aspx), which is found in `System.Data.Entity.SqlServer` in EF6 (`System.Data.Objects.SqlClient` in previous versions) in order to convert the `decimal` to a `string`:

```
dues_type = dues.due_type + " - " + SqlFunctions.StringConvert(dues.amount),
```

Answer (score 1):

There is [SqlFunctions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions(v=vs.110).aspx) class, which has utility methods, treated in special way, while converting expression tree to sql query and that's why invoked at db level, but it's available only for Entity Framework > 4 (if I'm not mistaken).

But you could concatenate your values at .NET side. Just use `AsEnumerable` for this kind of operations.

```
public IEnumerable<pmdues> GetDues()
{
    var pmDues = 
        from dues in ObjectContext.tblDuesRates
        orderby dues.due_type
        select new 
        {
            DuesID = dues.id,
            dues_type = dues.due_type,
            dues_amount = dues.amount.Value
        };    

    return pmDues
             .AsEnumerable()
             .Select(d => 
                 new pmDues()
                 { 
                     DuesID = d.DuesID, 
                     DuesType = d.dues_type + " - " + 
                                d.dues_amount.ToString()
                 });
}
```

But you won't be able to return `IQueryable` and thus perform filtering or sorting at db level then.

If upper level code, which invokes `GetDues`, really should perform such operations,
you can provide additional parameter of type `Func<IQueryable<pmdues>, IQueryable<pmdues>>` to your method and invoke it before `AsEnumerable`.

Answer (score 0):

Try with removing `.ToString()`

```
   public IQueryable<pmdues> GetDues()

      return from dues in ObjectContext.tblDuesRates
              orderby dues.due_type
     select new pmDues()
        {
          DuesID = dues.id,
          dues_type = dues.due_type + " - " + 
                      dues.amount.Value,
          dues_amount = dues.amount.Value
          };
    }
```

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos What do you mean ? `String + "_" + decimal` will not compiled in c# ??

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: You might want to try that. `"blah"+1M` is fine. That gets compiled into a call to String.Concat which can take objects just fine.

Comment: Oops. That still won't help with the question though - a call to `ToString()` will still be made by the framework itself. Removing `ToString()` won't change anything

Answer (score 0):

Making an assumption here but give this a go and see if it works for you.

```
public IQueryable<pmdues> GetDues()
{
    return (from dues in ObjectContext.tblDuesRates
           orderby dues.due_type).ToList().
           Select(x => new pmDues
           {
              DuesID = x.id,
              dues_type = string.Format("{0} - {1}",
                          x.due_type,
                          x.amount),
              dues_amount = x.amount.Value
           }).AsQueryable();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What is your problem here ? You can always use string concatenation with either way: `String.Concat(a, b, c.ToString())` or just `a + b + c.ToString()` and write this value to your string  ' `dues_type`  ' . What's wrong with this ?